# JSONArray and JSONObject for google calendar

Tags: android, json, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create an android app to read the information from google calender using the json output.

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this using JSONArray and JSONObject  options available in android sdk.

Greatly appreciate any help on this...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
// Query the API for content
        String content = getUrlContent(String.format(WIKTIONARY_PAGE,
                encodedTitle, expandClause));
        try {
            // Drill into the JSON response to find the content body
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONObject query = response.getJSONObject("query");
            JSONObject pages = query.getJSONObject("pages");
            JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject((String) pages.keys().next());
            JSONArray revisions = page.getJSONArray("revisions");
            JSONObject revision = revisions.getJSONObject(0);
            return revision.getString("*");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new ParseException("Problem parsing API response", e);
        }
```

Comment: appreciate the speedy response. I will try this and share my experience. Thanks again ...!!!

Comment: Thanks, if it helped can you select my answer.

Comment: I don't see the node query in google calender json output. I see node "Entry". How can I parse this to get the required information.